# Ruby перевернуть ответ на вопрос

Tags: ruby

Народ,не чего не идет в голову,есть задание на treehouse для практики.Надо написать слово,после спросить хочет ли что бы он был перевернет если "да" то переварачиваем,если нет то оставляет на месте.

Так вот не могу додуматся как def метод привоять к ответу.

Comment: Извините, не вполне разбираю ваш русский. Причешите вопрос до более русского языка, пожалуйста.

Comment: @D-side Вроде всё понятно, есть слово, задаётся вопрос "хочешь ли его перевернуть", если "да", то переворачиваешь слово :). Я так понял.

Comment: Перевернуть строку элементарно на Руби если в этом вопрос `puts "abc".reverse`

Comment: Да,не умею излагать мысль на русском,но учусь.

Comment: Спасибо,@Arty OneSoul,это я знаю:) но мне надо что то типо def method(string) if string=="reverse" puts string.reverse(string должен быть слово которое было написанно в начале программы)

Comment: @ŽansLitinskis Пока не понял что именно нужно про метод сделать, но вот [простейшая программа тут](https://repl.it/NGHR/0) для ввода строки, вопроса, и переворачивания.

Comment: воот то что надо,спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот написал простейшую программу на Ruby, хотя Ruby не знаю, потому она может быть как-то слишком примитивно написано и не в нужном стиле, [запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NGHR/2):

```
puts "Please, enter string..."
s = gets.chomp
puts "Do you want to reverse it (Yes/No)?"
is_rev = gets.chomp
s.reverse! if is_rev == "Yes"
puts "Result: [" + s + "]"
```

Comment: Неплохо! Касательно стиля -- `if`-выражение можно заменить на гард (guard expression) без присваивания: `s.reverse! if is_rev == "Yes"`.

Comment: @D-side Спасибо, подправил! :)